# transform the correlation matrix into a data frame in R

Tags: r

```
data(iris)
iris$Species<-NULL
cor(iris)
```

and get cor. matrix

```
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

let's get descriptive statistics

```
library(psych)
describe(iris)
```

and results

```
             vars   n mean   sd median trimmed  mad min max range  skew kurtosis   se
Sepal.Length    1 150 5.84 0.83   5.80    5.81 1.04 4.3 7.9   3.6  0.31    -0.61 0.07
Sepal.Width     2 150 3.06 0.44   3.00    3.04 0.44 2.0 4.4   2.4  0.31     0.14 0.04
Petal.Length    3 150 3.76 1.77   4.35    3.76 1.85 1.0 6.9   5.9 -0.27    -1.42 0.14
Petal.Width     4 150 1.20 0.76   1.30    1.18 1.04 0.1 2.5   2.4 -0.10    -1.36 0.06
```

There many statastics, but we need only on mean and sd

So the question.
if we have correlation between variables and we know mean and sd of these variable, how transform cor. matrix to data frame.
It is clear that most likely the values in the data frame will differ from the real ones.

Comment: Are you looking for `as.data.frame()` ? What will it differ from? Your question doesn't seem very clear?

Comment: Does that mean you want to generate based on data? If you just want to transform matrix to data.frame, i agree Rohit's answer.

Comment: @Rohit, i want, if i have cor matrix and mean and sd of variables , create dataframe , with data and  if with  these data  will performed correlation analysis, i get same cor matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified a probability distribution so I'm going to assume that you want a dataframe with a normal distribution, since you mention mean and covariance.

You can use the `mvrnorm()` function from the `MASS` package. It will generate a multivariate normal distribution, and will have a similiar corelation matric to the original set. But note that only the correlation and mean will be similiar for sure, unless the original datahas the same distribution.

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:MASS':
#> 
#>     select
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data("iris")
iris$Species<-NULL
C <- cov(iris) # Note covariance, not cor
mu <- colMeans(iris)
df <- as_tibble(mvrnorm(10000,mu,C))
cor(df)
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1269997    0.8728482   0.8220813
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1269997   1.0000000   -0.4334930  -0.3707066
#> Petal.Length    0.8728482  -0.4334930    1.0000000   0.9633552
#> Petal.Width     0.8220813  -0.3707066    0.9633552   1.0000000
cor(iris)
#>              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
#> Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
#> Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
#> Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```